# How to make RadGrid Lighter?

Tags: asp.net

My page contains a tabcontainer with 5 tabs. Each tab contains multiple RadGrids As RadGrid is heavier than ASP.NET gridview. My page lags i.e runs very slowly. My UI is very slow i.e switching between the tabs sometimes hangs the browser. I want to make the Telerik RadGrid lighter in order to make the browser handle multiple RadGrids & I cant remove the RadGrids because i have already written code according to Rad controls. I dont want interactive UI How can i remove extra UI functionality from RadGrid so that it will be as lighter as Normal ASP.Net GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find some helpful advice from Telerik directly: [Client/server grid performance optimizations](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-viewstate-reduction-techniques.html)

In particular, consider loading the content of the individual tabs on demand (ie: only after clicking on a tab).  The page will be much lighter and quicker.

Comment: Thanks, I am loading the tabs on demand only but after all controls are loaded onto the page. It starts working slowly

Comment: How large are the grids that are being added to the page?  Do you use paging on the grids?  You're going to have to minimize the amount of data in each tab.